# wp_customize is messing WordPress Media Library

Tags: wordpress, customization, media

I just made custom image section in WP Customize panel with this in functions.php

```
//Kuvaesitys

<?php
function tf_kuvaesitys($wp_customize) {
$wp_customize->add_section('tf-kuvaesitys-section', array(
    'title' => 'Kuvaesitys'
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('tf-kuvaesitys-kuvayksi');

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvayksi-control', array(
    'label' => 'Kuva 1',
    'section' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-section',
    'settings' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvayksi',
    'width' => 1500,
    'height' => 573
)));

$wp_customize->add_setting('tf-kuvaesitys-kuvakaksi');

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvakaksi-control', array(
    'label' => 'Kuva 2',
    'section' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-section',
    'settings' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvakaksi',
    'width' => 1500,
    'height' => 573
)));

$wp_customize->add_setting('tf-kuvaesitys-kuvakolme');

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvakolme-control', array(
    'label' => 'Kuva 3',
    'section' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-section',
    'settings' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvakolme',
    'width' => 1500,
    'height' => 573
)));

$wp_customize->add_setting('tf-kuvaesitys-kuvanelja');

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvanelja-control', array(
    'label' => 'Kuva 4',
    'section' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-section',
    'settings' => 'tf-kuvaesitys-kuvanelja',
    'width' => 1500,
    'height' => 573
)));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'tf_kuvaesitys');
?>
```

Now Media Library shows only list view (grid view is hanging with loader rolling) and when I upload images in Media Library it says "//Kuvaesitys" under "Maximum upload file size: 64MB" and in blue bar it says "Crunching...".

When uploading image in Customize view it gives this error message: "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

My wild guess is there's something in the php above that is doing this but I can't find out what.

Comment: Ah. It was the comment. Obvious but why. Is // -comment not allowed in functions.php?

Comment: Is this your whole functions.php file?

Comment: Only the part for little slideshow.